# Generate nonnegative variates with mean 1 and specified variance-covariance

Tags: simulation, covariance-matrix, copula, multivariate-distribution, survey-weights

#### Problem

In several applications in surveys, it would be helpful to be able to generate a set of $R$ $n$-dimensional variates with the following properties:

1. Has mean vector $1$
2. Has a specified variance-covariance matrix ($\Sigma$, a positive semi-definite matrix, with rank $\leq R$)
3. Is nonnegative

#### Some First Thoughts about Solutions

The first two requirements are easy to satisfy. We can just draw from a multivariate Normal distribution, as discussed here: [Generating data with a given sample covariance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/120179/94994)

But if we add the additional requirement that all of the variates are nonnegative, then a multivariate Normal distribution won't work. In the applications I have in mind (described below), typically the diagonal of $\Sigma$ has a few entries which are $1$ or even as large as $1.5$, so a multivariate Normal will easily generate negative values.

In this application, it doesn't matter at all what the skew or kurtosis are, and it doesn't matter whether the random variates come from a particular distribution. All that matters is that they're nonnegative, have mean vector $1$, and have the specified covariance matrix (ideally, it would have the exact specified **sample** covariance matrix, but it would be OK if it just had the specified covariance matrix in expectation).

The multivariate lognormal and Gamma distributions are nonnegative and [seem like fairly natural options](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439381/generate-multivariate-log-normal-variables-with-given-covariance-and-mean), except that there are constraints on their precise shape (due to their density functions) which mean that they will often not be able to attain the desired variance-covariance. So these parametric distributions, at least, seem unnecessarily limiting.

In low dimensions, one can generate random variates and then "fix them up" to satisfy constraints, at least approximately. This StackExchange gets at this kind of approach, but it doesn't really cover the constraint of nonnegativity and is really focused on a univariate case.

[How to simulate data that satisfy specific constraints such as having specific mean and standard deviation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30303/how-to-simulate-data-that-satisfy-specific-constraints-such-as-having-specific-m/71441#71441)

#### Motivating Application

In survey statistics, resampling methods such as the jackknife or bootstrap are typically implemented by generating replicate weights, which are random variates with a specific mean vector and covariance matrix. To be concrete, if one has a dataset of size $n$, then one generates $R$ sets of replicate weights, which can be represented as a matrix of dimension $R \times n$. In general, we want these replicate weights to be nonnegative, since the weights will frequently be used in statistical procedures that require nonnegative weights and usually even for many procedures that allow negative weights, the software implementations won't allow negative weights because they're just unexpected.

This R package vignette describes the generation of replicate weights for the "generalized survey bootstrap", and describes how multivariate normal distributions are used to generate replicate weights that have mean vector $1$ and a specified variance-covariance matrix, but which can sometimes be negative.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svrep/vignettes/bootstrap-replicates.html#forming-adjustment-factors
It also describes a rescaling adjustments that makes the random variates nonnegative and with mean vector $1$, but unfortunately that rescaling adjustment increases the variance-covariance by a constant (which is a problem).

Comment: Thanks- I added that tag to the question.

Comment: What I meant is that you should investigate *copulas* as a direct manner of imposing a given covariance matrix on rv's with given margins.

Comment: Yes, that seems promising, although I'm not sure it will 100% work

Comment: A copula with gamma marginals seems promising for example, but is limited by the fact that Gamma variables with different scales are restricted in the possible covariances they can have.

Comment: Copulae could be a real pain (after having to use them for multivariate Gamma), however here's one good beginners' tutorial: https://twiecki.io/blog/2018/05/03/copulas/

Comment: Another option you should check out is the folded normal distribution, more specifically the multivariate folded normal: https://www.jstor.org/stable/42003783

Comment: What were typical/interesting sizes for $R$ and $n$? I ask because attempts at direct computational solutions may not work well for those being large.

Comment: That's a good point. A typical value of $n$ would be something like $1,000$ and $R$ could be anywhere between $50$ and $1,000$. The value of $n$ is determined by the sample size of the survey, and the value of $R$ is chosen to balance data storage / computation costs (lower values of $R$ better) against the desire for more precise variance estimation (higher values of $R$ better).

Comment: I doubt that copulas will work well. Covariance is not a property of the copula alone, but of both copula and margins. It seems this is also the root cause for the problem having no solution in general. Certain margins are just incompatible with certain covariance matrices.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you could give some examples of Σ you are interested in. Wouldn't those matrices not fulfill additional properties from the specific use case? For example [exchangeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables#Covariance_and_correlation)?

Answer (score 2):

First notice that the requirements of non-negativity and mean equals 1 cannot be simultaneously satisfied for an *arbitrary* covariance matrix: if $x_i$ is the $i$-th variate ($i=1...n$) with $E[x_i]=1$, then

$$Cov(x_i,x_j)=E[(x_i-1)(x_j-1)]=E[x_ix_j]-1 \ge -1$$

since all the $x_i$'s are nonnegative and therefore $E[x_ix_j] \ge 0$. This implies that all the entries of the covariance matrix $\Sigma_{ij}$ has to be larger than -1, which is a non-trivial constraint. (Note that the same argument applies to the sample covariance. Also note that it does not imply that if $\Sigma_{ij} \ge -1$ then necessarily a solution exists; there might be other constraints).

If you are not interested in the generating distribution but just want to find some matrix $X$ which has the specified properties (assuming it exists), a straightforward approach might be to try to minimize a sum of squared errors using a gradient descent algorithm. To ensure nonnegativity the elements of $X$ can be parametrized e.g. with $X_{in} = e^{W_{in}}$, and you can take advantage of auto-differentiation libraries to calculate the gradients for you.

Here is for example an implementation in PyTorch, which finds a (approximate) solution for $R=20, n=3$ in about 2 seconds:

```py
import torch

R, n = 20, 3

#generate n-by-n random covariance matrix with entries larger than -1
S=torch.Tensor([-2])
while S.min() < -1:
    A = torch.randn(n,n)/2
    S = A.matmul(A.T)


def loss(W,S):
    [R,n]=W.shape
    X = torch.exp(W)
    sse = (torch.cov(X.T,correction = 0) - S).square().sum() + (X.mean(0)-torch.ones(n)).square().sum()
    return sse

#initialize W with random entries
W = torch.randn(R,n,requires_grad=True)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([W],lr=0.05)

for iter in range(1000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    L = loss(W,S)
    L.backward()
    optimizer.step()

print(f'sse = {L}')
X=torch.exp(W)
print('specified covariance:')
print(S)
print('sample covariance:')
print(torch.cov(X.T,correction = 0))
print('mean:')
print(X.mean(0))
```

output:

```
sse = 0.007093742955476046
specified covariance:
tensor([[ 1.9820, -0.2131, -0.5573],
        [-0.2131,  0.8370, -0.0203],
        [-0.5573, -0.0203,  0.1815]])
sample covariance:
tensor([[ 1.9881, -0.2122, -0.5349],
        [-0.2122,  0.8371, -0.0169],
        [-0.5349, -0.0169,  0.2584]], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward0>)
mean:
tensor([1.0026, 1.0003, 1.0093], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>)
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your comment about the constraints the nonnegativity and mean requirements imply for the covariance matrix. For the gradient descent algorithm, I wonder how feasible this would be in real applications, where you might have $n=10,000$ and $50 \leq R \leq 1,000$. That's a lot of parameters to try to directly optimize.

Comment: That number of parameters ($R \times n$) is still quite small compared to typical deep learning models which use the same optimization algorithm. I am curious however, from where do you get a $10,000$-by-$10,000$ matrix with rank $50$ ?

Comment: Let me clarify. The application here is creating $R$ length-$n$ vectors of replicate weights, when you have a dataset with $n$ observations and you create $R$ resamples of your data. This is commonly done to represent replication variance estimators such as the bootstrap, where we can choose a suitably large number of replications $R$. So we’re generating a $(R \times n)$ matrix, and the covariance matrix of these $R$ vectors has dimension $n \times n$.

Comment: I see that, but you want the resulting covariance matrix to be equal to $\Sigma$ which is pre-specified (and needs to have rank $R$). Where does this $\Sigma$ come from ?

Comment: Ah, ok. The $\Sigma$ is chosen to represent a variance estimator appropriate for a given sampling method (SRS, stratified sampling, cluster sampling, etc.) The [section of this page titled "Generalized Survey Bootstrap"](https://bschneidr.github.io/svrep/articles/bootstrap-replicates.html#generalized-survey-bootstrap) goes into more detail. As a specific example, in the case of simple random sampling without replacement, $\Sigma$ is a matrix with diagonal elements equal to $1$ and all non-diagonal elements equal to $-(n-1)^{-1}$. For this special case, jackknife weights work perfectly.

Comment: This sounds like you are not interested in a solution for generic $\Sigma$ but in very specific highly structured examples. Since in general a solution may not exist as @J.Delaney has demonstrated, it might be much smarter to start with one of the special cases and take it from there?

Comment: @bschneidr $\Sigma$ in your example has rank $n-1$. Since you want $R \ll n$, you clearly can't get this sample covariance (or even a reasonable low rank approximation, since all non-zeros eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ are close to 1)

Comment: This solution seems to work as well as anything else I've seen. The parameterization of this problem and the suggestion to use one of the gradient descent algorithms available in PyTorch seems quite promising. Would you be OK if edit the answer to add an R equivalent of the code you provided? Thanks again.

Comment: Of course, feel free to add your own implementation